# pass parameter to javascript function in asp.net Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, parameters

I want to pass a parameter to a JavaScript function to use in document.getElementByID() as follows:

```
function PrinGridView(GridViewname)
{

 var TableRow= document.getElementByID("GridViewname").getElementsBytagName("tr");

 var td= TableRow.item(0).getElementsBytagName("th");


 if(td.length>0)
   alert('done');
 
}
```

In my asp page, I have an image button event:

```
onClicke="PrinGridView("<%=MyGrideView.ClientID%>")";
```

but it does not work well.

How can I pass the GridView to a function?

Thanks.

Comment: In `document.getElementByID("GridViewname")`, `GridViewName` shouldn't be in quotes

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is **case sensitive**; it's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`, `getElementsByTagName` not `getElementsBytagName` etc.

There are other typos; F12 in your browser and the Error/Console will display script errors.

You need to mix quotes as the below is not valid, aside from the typo its not a parseable string as the quotes are broken:

```
onClicke="PrinGridView("<%=MyGrideView.ClientID%>")";
```

Change to

```
onClick="PrinGridView('<%=MyGrideView.ClientID%>')";
```

Within the function you quote what should probably be the argument, change from

```
var TableRow = document.getElementByID("GridViewname")
```

to

```
var TableRow= document.getElementById(GridViewname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there, onClicke. This is wrong, should be onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

onClick="PrinGridView(this)"

```
function PrinGridView(obj)
{
var gridName = obj.id;
 var TableRow= document.getElementByID(gridName).getElementsBytagName("tr");

 var td= TableRow.item(0).getElementsBytagName("th");


 if(td.length>0)
   alert('done');

}
```

Comment: I have more than one grid view in same page (I use the AJAX TabContainer)

Answer (score -1):

this works perfectly for inline code

OnClientClick='<%#String.Format("buttonstatus(""{0}"",""{1}"",""{2}"",""{3}"");return false;", Eval("listingid"), "D", "Archived", Eval("EndDate"))%>'